# WCF Json deserialization preserve polymorphic collection types

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

WCF Json deserialization.

I'm building a middleware webservice in WCF using Dotnet 4.5, This server returns a polymorphic type.

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SomethingA))]
[KnownType(typeof(SomethingB))]
public class Something
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Item1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SomethingA : Something
{ }

[DataContract]
public class SomethingB : Something
{ }


/// <summary>
/// Contract for a service for testing various web operations.
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomethingA))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomethingB))]
public interface ITesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Test passing in and returning an object using POST and json.
    /// </summary>
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "use-polymorphic-somethings",
        Method = "POST")]
    List<Something> UsePolymorphicSomethings();
}

/// <summary>
/// Implementation of the ITesting service contract.
/// </summary>
public class Testing : ITesting
{
    public List<Something> UsePolymorphicSomethings()
    {
        List<Something> retVal = new List<Something>();
        retVal.Add(new SomethingA { Item1 = 1, Item2 = "1" });
        retVal.Add(new SomethingB { Item1 = 1, Item2 = "1" });
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

On the client side I'm attempting to deserialize this in such a way as to preserve the different types in the collection. The MSDN documentation for this seems really weak to me. The first issue I encountered was that adding a reference to System.Web.Http created an undocumented dynamic dependency on on a third party open source component called Newtonsoft.Json which I had to download off the web.

The first two deserialization approaches fail, but I have found a third approach that works.

What I'd like to know is why do the first two approaches fail? Ideally I'd like to get the first approach to work as that is the most streamlined.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void UsePolymorphicSomethings_Test1()
{
    using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
    {
        http.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8733/");

        HttpResponseMessage response = http.PostAsJsonAsync(
        "Design_Time_Addresses/InSite8WebServiceLib2/Testing/use-polymorphic-somethings",
        new StringContent(string.Empty)).Result;

        List<Something> ret = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Something>>().Result;

        // FAILS.
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SomethingA), somethings[0].GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SomethingB), somethings[1].GetType());
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void UsePolymorphicSomethings_Test2()
{
    using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
    {
        http.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8733/");

        HttpResponseMessage response = http.PostAsJsonAsync(
        "Design_Time_Addresses/InSite8WebServiceLib2/Testing/use-polymorphic-somethings",
        new StringContent(string.Empty)).Result;

        string ret1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings s = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
        s.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All;
        List<Something> r = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Something>>(ret1, s);

        // FAILS.
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SomethingA), somethings[0].GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SomethingB), somethings[1].GetType());
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void UsePolymorphicSomethings_Test3()
{
    using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
    {
        http.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8733/");

        HttpResponseMessage response = http.PostAsJsonAsync(
        "Design_Time_Addresses/InSite8WebServiceLib2/Testing/use-polymorphic-somethings",
        new StringContent(string.Empty)).Result;

        Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Something>));
        List<Something> somethings = (List<Something>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

        // SUCCEEDS.
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SomethingA), somethings[0].GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SomethingB), somethings[1].GetType());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I believe the reason the last method is working and the other two not. Is because when you use WebMessageFormat.Json, the serializer that is used server side is the DataContractJsonSerializer. so it makes sense that using the same serializer both server and client side, would end up in a happy result. If you want to use NewstonSoft for example, you would have to serer side, make create a message formatter class, a web http behaviour, a behaviour extension element and a web content type mapper and then you need to hook all those up, possibly in the web or app config files.

Comment: I see. In that case UsePolymorphicSomethings_Test1 must be using a different JSON capable deserializer (since it does perform the deserialization, just incorrectly), which raises several questions. Which JSON serializer does ReadAsAsync use by default? Why does it not use the DataContractJsonSerializer by default? and can ReadAsAsync not be configured to use the DataContractJsonSerializer by default since its default configuration is useless?

Comment: I don't really want to use Newtonsoft if I don't have to, the only reason I tried to deserialize using the Newtonsoft classes is because System.Net.Http in my integration test assembly created a dynamic (runtime) dependence on it which caused me to surmise that it might be related to this issue in some way.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you are "worried" about the stream lining of the code that you have written. Seeing that you have the code working in your last method, and I hope my reasons for it working and the others not explain it to your satisfaction. We can still stream line you method a bit using a simple helper.

```
public T Deserialize<T>(Stream stream) where T : class
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
```

you can then simply call this method like so

```
List<Something> somethings = Deserialize<List<Something>>(stream);
```

To make things maybe even easier in a sense, you could write the helper method as a extension method,
something like this

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this Stream stream) where T : class
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

You could then call this method like this

```
var result = stream.Deserialize<List<Something>>();
```

To go all the way up, you could create the extension method against the HttpResponseMessage

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this HttpResponseMessage response) where T : class
    {
        var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

You could call this method like this

```
var result = response.Deserialize<List<Something>>();
```

At least your code will now again be a one liner and if you in the future change your serializer, you will only have to change your client code in a single place. you might want to check the code out, as I don't have visual studio open currently to test it out for you. But it looks good to me.

I am adding a new helper example here, so there are more options / fixes to choose from.

```
 public static class Helpers
{
    public static Task<T> ReadAsAsyncCustom<T>(this HttpContent content)
    {
        var formatters = new MediaTypeFormatterCollection();
        formatters.Clear();
        formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter { UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true });
        return content.ReadAsAsync<T>(formatters);
    }
}
```

and this one could be used as follows

```
List<Something> ret = response.Content.ReadAsAsyncCustom<List<Something>>().Result;
```

The reason I call clear on the formatter variable in the helper method, is because the constructor of the MediaTypeFormatterCollection creates default formatters, we are not interested in those, so I clear them and add in just 1 formatter that we know works with your solution.

I generally try stick to the DRY rule, which is the reason I try keep "customisation" isolated in just a single place, so that when things change, I don't need to go through all the source and try remember or search for all the instances where it may have been used.

to put things in another way as well, while the framework does support your scenario, it of course requires a settings change if you will. If you were not using what you call polymorphic types, the standard out of the box methods would work great. I wrote up a solution mimicking yours this morning, and I could not see a quick way that could help you get away without making changes on your client side.

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't clear enough. I'm trying to understand what deserialization mechanism ReadAsAsync uses that results in it deserializing the JSON incorrectly, not just hide the workaround code in another method.

Comment: Hi Neutrino, thanks for clearing that up. Jose is in fact touching on the point well. The problem client side is exactly as he said, and yes sending the parameters as he stated does fix the issue, however, either way you are going to have to "change" the way the code would work out the box. so unless you only have one call in the application, I would still recommend that you make use of a helper class with an extension method, or at least something along those lines. At least as in my example the "customisation" is in a single place and should something change in the future, changing is simple

Comment: So besides that the above examples work that I put out for you, I am going to update it now, to include one more method and you can choose what would be best to use for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, methods 1 and 2 instantiate an object of type T and then set its properties by reading the stream. In other words, these methods only known the type "Something" so they can only instantiate "Something". Third method also uses attributes DataContract and KnownType, so it is able to instantiate the known types "Something", "SomethingA" and "SomethingB".

[image]

Comment: That's _what_ is happening. I'm trying to understand _why_ this is happening. In UsePolymorphicSomethings_Test1 the ReadAsAsync method must be using some form of deserialization internally, the JSON transferred clearly contains the necessary type information that facilitates polymorphic deserialization (since UsePolymorphicSomethings_Test3 works fine), so the question remains what deserialization mechanism is ReadAsAsync using by default and why doesn't that deserialize correctly.

Comment: ReadAsAsync does not serialize correctly because it does not use the attributes DataContract and KnownType. By default, ReadAsAsync uses [JsonMediaTypeFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.jsonmediatypeformatter%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) with UseDataContractJsonSerializer property set to false. If you want to serialize using these attributes you need to use a DataContractJsonSerializer or ReadAsAsync passing new[]{new JsonMediaTypeFormatter{UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true}} . I edited my initial response to set an example of this.